# Continues Speech Recognition beep sound after Google Search update

Tags: android, auto-update, voice-recognition, voice

I have an app that keeps on listening to voice and converting it to commands using Google Voice API.

I have been using `setStreamMute(AudioManager.STREAM_SYSTEM, true)` to mute the beep and it worked until a couple of days ago before "Google Search" new update.
Is there any workaround fix for it?

I know I can use `setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT)`, but maybe there is another method?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the update they switched the output of the 'beep' to the media stream.

So you'll need to mute the [AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html#STREAM_MUSIC)

There's an enhancement request about it [here](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=37862)

Comment: `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS"/>` do not forget like me.

Answer (score 3):

Mute the beep by muting the notification sound:

```
(getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE) as AudioManager).adjustStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_NOTIFICATION, AudioManager.ADJUST_MUTE,0)
```

Make sure to unmute it after you start listening:

```
(getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE) as AudioManager).adjustStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_NOTIFICATION, AudioManager.ADJUST_UNMUTE,0)
```

Please note that there's a beep sound when the listening stops.

Answer (score 1):

The beep sound can be muted by using `AudioManager`

```
AudioManager mAudioManager =(AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
mAudioManager.setStreamMute(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, true);
```

To unmute sound

```
AudioManager mAudioManager =(AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
mAudioManager.setStreamMute(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, false);
```

Also add permission to Manifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS"/>
```